# Whats more efficient?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have 2 kinds of users:

1. Employees
2. Recruiters

Recruiters can make vacancies.

A vacancy can have requirements and an employee also has/or doesn't have these requirements:

1. Transportation(car, licence, ...)
2. Language(English, Dutch, French, German, ...)
3. Jobterm(employee, freelance, student, intern, ...)
4. Sector (logistics, retail, cleaning, ...)
5. Regimes (fulltime, parttime, holidays, weekends, ...)

In my current database structure I have tables for all 5 of these requirements and foreign keys.

My question is; everytime I'm loading a Vacancy, it needs to get the FK value out of all these models, and thus, loading 6 models every time I want to display something in my view.

Isn't it more efficient since they are only 1 column tables to put the values directly into the models and make sure that front-end wise the user cannot enter any other values?

Or is there another way to reduce load-times (or is this a non-issue?).

Thank you.

Comment: Denormalization can be beneficial, yes. In addition to client-side UI checks you should implement server validations too.

Comment: In SQL the fully fully indexed joins to get these items should be very efficient and fast (and saves storing repeated details for those fields in your main table). But if you are using some kind of framework which translates those in to objects when you read the records then this might destroy the performance.

Comment: On top of what is already said - to simplify your rails code (and escape all includes/joins etc) you can benefit from database views. There was a good talk on London Ruby User Group meeting some time ago: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6127-whos-afraid-of-database-views